# how to create multiple arrays of random numbers for javascript data-randomizer?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, random

I am building a data randomizer in javascript for a history class which I teach. I want a user to enter into a form number of students, number of weeks, and number of assignmnets per each student and submit this data by clicking a button. For example 40 students, 12 weeks, 5 assignments for each student. Accordingly, I want the program to generate a table of 40 rows each containing 5 random unique numbers from 1 to 12. I managed to make the program generate one row of random numbers (function weeksAssigned), but then I got stuck. How do I repeat function weeksAssigned to produce other rows? I was trying to use two dimensional arrays, but I don't know how to randomize each row inside the 2d array. I will be very grateful for your suggestions! I guess I should somehow utilize either a for loop or 2d arrays, but I am not sure how.

```
function getRandomWeek() {
    var x,y;
    x = document.getElementById("form1").elements["duration"].value; 
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * x + 1);
    return y;
} 

function weeksAssigned() {
    var ints = [];
    var assignments = document.getElementById("form1").elements["assignments"].value; 
    while (ints.length < assignments) {                                                    
        var randomWeak = getRandomWeek();
        if (ints.indexOf(randomWeak)===-1) {   
          ints.push(randomWeak);
        }
    } 
    ints.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    return ints;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it by looping over each student and then over each assigment.

I first create a 2d array filled with `0` having as many rows as there are students and as many columns as there are assignments:

```
const assignArr = Array.from({ length: assignments }, (_, i) => 0);
const studentsArr = Array.from({ length: students }, (_, i) => [...assignArr]);
```

Then, you use two loops to fill this array with random weeks. For each student, you initialize the available weeks at the beginning of the loop and you pass this array to `getRandomWeeks()` which removes a random week from the array so you don't repeat them for each student:

```
for (let student = 0; student < students; ++student) {
    const weeks = Array.from({ length: duration }, (_, i) => i);
    for (let work = 0; work < assignments; ++work) {
        studentsArr[student][work] = getRandomWeek(weeks) + 1;
    }
    studentsArr[student].sort((a, b) => a - b);
}

function getRandomWeek(weeks) {
  const weekIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * weeks.length);
  return weeks.splice(weekIdx, 1).shift();
}
```

Then you just call a helper function to generate the table. Here is a complete demo. You can edit the form fields and see the table update:

```js
function update() {
  const form = document.getElementById('form');
  const duration = form.elements['weeks'].value;
  const students = form.elements['students'].value;
  const assignments = form.elements['assignments'].value;
  
  const assignArr = Array.from({ length: assignments }, (_, i) => 0);
  const studentsArr = Array.from({ length: students }, (_, i) => [...assignArr]);
  
  for (let student = 0; student < students; ++student) {
    const weeks = Array.from({ length: duration }, (_, i) => i);
    for (let work = 0; work < assignments; ++work) {
      studentsArr[student][work] = getRandomWeek(weeks) + 1;
    }
    studentsArr[student].sort((a, b) => a - b);
  }
  makeTable(studentsArr);
}

function getRandomWeek(weeks) {
  const weekIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * weeks.length);
  return weeks.splice(weekIdx, 1).shift();
}

function makeTable(data) {
  const header = document.querySelector('#table thead tr');
  header.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < data[0].length + 1; ++i) {
    const colEl = document.createElement('th');
    colEl.textContent = i === 0 ? 'Assignments' : `#${i}`;
    header.appendChild(colEl);
  }
  const tbody = document.querySelector('#table tbody');
  tbody.innerHTML = '';
  data.forEach((row, i) => {
    const rowEl = document.createElement('tr');
    const col0 = document.createElement('td');
    col0.textContent = `Student #${i + 1}`;
    rowEl.appendChild(col0);
    for (let col of row) {
      const colEl = document.createElement('td');
      colEl.textContent = col;
      rowEl.appendChild(colEl);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(rowEl);
  });
}

update();
```

```css
table {
  margin: 10px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  Weeks <input type="number" name="weeks" value=12 onchange="update()">
  Students <input type="number" name="students" value=10 onchange="update()">
  Assignments <input type="number" name="assignments" value=5 onchange="update()">
</form>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome, I added sorting on the entries, so the weeks are ordered. Thank you for upvoting if it helped! :)

Comment: I did, but it says: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I've got just 8 so far, I just registered here. As soon as I get 15 I will upvote it, I promise!

Comment: Don't worry :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is loop `weeksAssigned` and push the values in a 2d array.

To help you with that, check the code below:

```
var students = document.getElementById("form1").elements["students"].value;
var studentsAssignList = [];
for(var i = 0; i < students; i++){
    var assignList = weeksAssigned();
    studentsAssignList.push(assignList);
}
// `studentsAssignList` will be your 2d array of all the assignments for all the students
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please clarify something. To display the result on the screen I used the following function: function getResult() {
var students = document.getElementById("form1").elements["students"].value;
var studentsAssignList = [];
for(var i = 0; i < students; i++){
    var assignList = weeksAssigned();
    studentsAssignList.push(assignList);
}
document.write(studentsAssignList);
}.  But it does not display all the rows, just one. How should I make it show all rows of the 2d array?